# Java exception com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/Instantiatable

Tags: java, json, jackson

Hi I'm getting the following exception while trying to convert an object to JSON string. I'm not sure why this error is showing?

```
    String json = "";
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    try 
    {
        // Convert our object to a string
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(obj); <----Exception throwing code
    } 
    catch (JsonProcessingException e) 
    {
        ConsoleLog.DisplayToConsole("Exception: parse JSON: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I have added the jackson Lib's:

[image: Lib Dir]

Object definition I'm trying trying to convert to JSON:

```
public class AccData extends AbstractData
{
private static ArrayList<Float> Acc_For = new ArrayList<Float>();
private static ArrayList<Float> Acc_Side = new ArrayList<Float>();
private static ArrayList<Float> Acc_Up = new ArrayList<Float>();


public static ArrayList<Float> getAccFor()
{
    return Acc_For;
}

public static ArrayList<Float> getAcSide()
{
    return Acc_Side;
}

etc
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/Instantiatable
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configureJsonGenerator(ObjectWriter.java:729)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:601)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:530)
at controller.JSONController.ObjectToJSON(JSONController.java:35)
at controller.MongoDBController.generateJSONStrings(MongoDBController.java:64)
at view.ChartWindow$1.widgetSelected(ChartWindow.java:164)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at view.ChartWindow.main(ChartWindow.java:186)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.Instantiatable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I removed the jackson-annotations.jar folder and added a newer version. But now I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect

Thrown here (as above):

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.<clinit>(VisibilityChecker.java:172)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:195)
at controller.JSONController.ObjectToJSON(JSONController.java:32)
at controller.MongoDBController.generateJSONStrings(MongoDBController.java:64)
at view.ChartWindow$1.widgetSelected(ChartWindow.java:164)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at view.ChartWindow.main(ChartWindow.java:186)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 11 more
```

Comment: You haven't posted the stack trace. Please post the COMPLETE stack trace (with all "Caused By" sections) and identify the line in your code that throws the exception.

Comment: You should use a real dependency manager like for example maven, instead of building a "lib" folder manually

Comment: Looking at the dependencies of jackson-databind it depends on jackson-annotations as well as jackson-core http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml.jackson.core%7Cjackson-databind%7C2.7.3%7Cbundle

Answer (score 2):

I think you are including the wrong version of Jackson Core.

I downloaded the JavaDoc for the Jackson Core 2.0.0-RC1, shown in the screen shot, from Maven Central.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml.jackson.core%7Cjackson-core%7C2.0.0-RC1%7Cbundle

The com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util package there does not have the missing Instantiatable class.

The JavaDoc for the latest version does.

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/Instantiatable.html

The NoClassDefFoundError exception is thrown when a referenced class cannot be found on the classpath at runtime. The com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter class is attempting to load the missing class. So the com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar would have been built against a different version of Jackson Core.

I would try replacing the jars you have with the latest versions of the Jackson Core, Annotation and Databind jars from Maven Central.